# Problema para conectar con ADB

Tags: android-studio, adb

Después de instalar Android Studio obtuve el siguiente error en el Event Log que se repite infinitamente

```
2:47 PM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

2:47 PM could not read ok from ADB Server

2:47 PM * failed to start daemon

2:47 PM error: cannot connect to daemon

2:47 PM 'D:\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

Traté de iniciar el servicio desde CMD pero la pantalla se queda pasmada (después de agregar mi carpeta platform-tools a la variable PATH)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ADB es necesario para probar las apps en el Teléfono o Emulador

Cuál puede ser el problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les comparto como lo solucioné por si a alguien más le sucede

usando el comando netstat encontré que el puerto que usa ADB ya estaba en uso por otro proceso

```
netstat -a -n -o
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer otro proceso esaba escuchando en ese puerto por lo decidí buscarlo con tasklist

```
tasklist /fi "PID eq 4916"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al ser un proceso de sistema no se puede matar asi como asi, por lo que investigando un poco mas encontré la forma cambiar el puerto donde escucha el ADB. Solo hay que agregar una nueva variable de entorno:

Variable: ANDROID_ADB_SERVER_PORT

Valor: 5038

Y listo, espero que esto pueda ayudar a alguien en el futuro.

Comment: de mucha ayuda tu respuesta, esto sucede frecuentemente, en otros casos  el proceso del ADB se queda abierto después de un error no determinado, hay que cerrar este proceso y abrirlo.